# Is the C part of the C++ library automatically C99?

Tags: c++, c, c99, standard-library

Are all the functions in a conformant C++98/03/0x implementation completely C99 conformant?

I thought C++0x added some C99 (*language*) features, but never heard or read anything definitive about the C library functions.

Just to avoid any confusion, I'm talking about a C++ program using functions declared in the `<c*>` header set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the C99 standard library has been imported in C++0X but not all.  From memory, in what wasn't imported there are

- `<ctgmath>` simply includes `<ccomplex>` and `<cmath>`,
- `<ccomplex>` behaves as if it included `<complex>`
- `<cmath>` has quite a few adjustment (providing overload and template functions completing the C99 provided one)
- Some other headers (`<cstdbool>`, `<iso646.h>`, ...) have adjustments to take differences between language into account (`bool` is primitive in C++, a macro provided by `<stdbool.h>` in C for instance), but nothing of the scope of the math part.

The headers `<xxx.h>` whose `<cxx>` form doesn't behaves as the C99 version simply declares the content of `<cxxx>` in the global namespace, they aren't nearer of the C99 `<xxx.h>` content.

A related thing: C++0X provides some headers in both cxxx and xxx.h forms which aren't defined in C99 (`<cstdalign>` and `<cuchar>`, the second one is defined in a C TR)

(I remembered that a bunch of mathematical functions from C99 had been put in TR1 but not kept in C++0X, I was mistaken, that bunch of mathematical functions weren't part of C99 in the first place).

Answer (score 4):

No. C++03 is aligned with ANSI C89/ISO C90, not C99.

The upcoming C++0x standard is expected to be aligned to some degree with C99. See paragraph 17.6.1.2 in the [current draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3126.pdf) which lists `ccomplex`, `cinttypes`, `cstdint` etc. Note that, as AProgrammer mentions, some headers aren't exactly the same; further, that the header `cuchar` is aligned with the [C Technical Report 19769](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1040.pdf) rather than C99.

Comment: The content for some headers isn't the C99 content.

Comment: @AProgrammer: you mean `cuchar` etc.? That's correct, but I never said that the headers contents are exactly the same (and gave you a +1 for specifying some differences). Will put some more detail into my answer, without copying yours.